# ZF2 SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I've got the error "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined" while trying to save an array into a related InnoDB, which makes no sense to me because I've already used the same method multiple times in the same Application and the DB connection seems to work as well because I can read and delete entries without any problems.

I've checked a lot of similar questions in hope they would resolve mine but haven't found one that resolved my problem.

This is the method I use to save to create the array and save it into the DB:

```
 public function saveBest(Besten $besten)
{
    $GePunkte = (int) $besten->Punkte/$besten->Dauer;

    $data = array(
        'GePunkte'  => $GePunkte,
        'Name'      => $besten->Name,
        'Zeitpunkt' => $besten->Zeitpunkt,
        'Punkte'    => $besten->Punkte,
        'Dauer'     => $besten->Dauer,
        'GewäKat'   => $besten->GewäKat,
    );
    print_r($data);


    $this->tableGateway->insert($data);


}
```

I've already used "print_r($data)" to check if the data in the array is complete because I suspected this to be the cause of the error.

print_r displayed the following:

```
Array ( [GePunkte] => 0.125 [Name] => Test [Zeitpunkt] => 1451480345 [Punkte] => 1 [Dauer] => 8 [GewäKat] => Natur )
```

At the same time I checked if the values of each param matches the datatypes set in the DB. GePunkte is set as float, Name as text, Zeitpunkt as int, Punkte as int, Dauer as int and GewäKat as text, so all values are inside the set boundaries.

I've also checked if I've got all the params named right by checking the insert sql command in Phpmyadmin and it's:

```
INSERT INTO `bestenliste`(`Sid`, `GePunkte`, `Name`, `Zeitpunkt`, `Punkte`, `Dauer`, `GewäKat`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7])
```

Since Sid is created automatically this seems to be alright too.

I can't figure out why it isn't working as it should, since everything else in the application seams to work perfectly fine, and because the deadline for this application is tomorrow at midnight I'm kinda in a hurry to resolve this problem.

So does anyone know a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried this with using GewaeKat instead of GewäKat? Might be that InnoDB has a different encoding and therefore does not recognize the parameter.

Comment: I just tried it and it works perfectly now. Thank you for your great suggsetion, I didn't think of that at all !